# Get content of an xml file from SFTP server in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, sftp, laravel-5.5

I keep getting this error when i try to get an xml file from SFTP server:

**file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "sftp" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?**

the code in controller:

```
    $host = 'xxxx';
    $username = 'xxxx';
    $password = 'xxxx';

    $sftp = new SFTP($host);

    if (!$sftp->login($username, $password)) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }

    $abc = $sftp->get('/xxxx/xxxxx.xml'); (this line works fine but it 
    displays as normal text)

    $get=file_get_contents('sftp://xxxxxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxx.xml');
    $arr = simplexml_load_string($get);
    print_r($arr); (while using these 3 lines I get that error)
```

Would really appreciate if someone could help me out, thanks.

Comment: "*this line works fine but it displays as normal text*" Displaying it as normal text would make sense if you echo'd it out. Maybe do `print_r(simplexml_load_string($abc));` on it?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the wrapper for `file_get_contents` is a bit different. Try something like this:

```
file_get_contents('ssh2.sftp://user:pass@example.com:22/path/to/filename');
```

Edit:

Take a look at the documentation. Here is a part for sftp.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php

You can see on top the package (PECL ssh2 >= 0.9.0). So you have to install the module first.

https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2

The other lib you use has it's own implementation.

Comment: Tried, but now i get 
file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper &quot;ssh2.sftp&quot; - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?